# Reading csv files from a directory and storing the data to a multi-index Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, indexing, io

I have csv files stored in a folder which contain fundamental data.  The folder looks like this:

[image]

Once imported as a Pandas dataframe a typical file looks like this:

[image]

I would like to build code that will read through a loop the files from the directory and do the following:

1) Set as Index the column 'Quarter end'.

2) Convert the column to datetime object

3) Convert the dataframe to a multi-indexed dataframe which will have a high level index in the axis = 1 dimension with the name 'Company' and the value of the index will be the name of the company of the particular file.  (So under the name of a given company will be all the columns containing fundamental data of the particular company.  This will be important in the second step where I will merge the files into one.)

4) Merge the files into one file using the index.  A key observation is that the indexes do not always match.  E.g. for the first five files the first values of the index --set to be 'Quarter end'-- are the following:

```
Index(['2018-01-31', '2017-10-31', '2017-07-31', '2017-04-30',...
Index(['2018-03-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-09-30', '2017-06-30', '2017-03-31',...
Index(['2018-03-31', '2017-12-31', '2017-09-30', '2017-06-30', '2017-03-31',..
Index(['2017-12-30', '2017-10-07', '2017-07-15', '2017-04-22', '2016-12-31',
Index(['2018-03-31', '2017-12-30', '2017-09-30', '2017-07-01', '2017-04-01',
```

My approach up to now is the following:

1) Amass the filenames in a list:

```
import os
os.chdir('D:\\DIGITAL_LIBRARY\\Corporate_fundamental_data\\Version_8_2018')
filenames = os.listdir()
```

2) Loop over the list and read the files

for file in filenames:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filenames[file], index_col = False).iloc[:, 1:]
```

3) Set as index the columb 'Quarter end'

```
df.set_index('Quarter end', inplace = True)
```

4) Convert to datetime object

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Now I would like to convert it to a multi-indexed object as I said in the beginning and give the appropriate value to the index using the name of the company which will be extracted from the file iterator (e.g., from 'A.csv' will be extracted 'A' which is easy)

5. Then I will store them to a Dictionary one at a time giving to each a key name which will be the name of the company.
6. Then I will loop over the dictionary and merge the files using their Indices
7. Finally I will fill forward the gaps created due to mismatches of the Indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

DATA_DIR = '/path/to/csv_file_dir/'

all_companies_df = pd.DataFrame()
for _company_fn in os.listdir(DATA_DIR):
    _company_df = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR + _company_fn)
    _company_df.set_index('Quarter End', inplace=True)
    _company_name = _company_fn.split('_')[0]
    _company_df.columns = \
        pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[_company_name], _company_df.columns.tolist()])

    all_companies_df = pd.concat((all_companies_df, _company_df), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Still something I am doing wrong.  Could you please have a look at the code I posted and advise me?

Comment: The directory path you use in the second code block is correct. The line at which you receive the `KeyError: 'Quarter End'` error is because 'Quarter End' is not a column name in the data. Should it be 'Quarter end' instead?

Comment: Thank you.  Indeed I corrected 'End' with 'end' and it runs.  It has been running now for 15 minutes. I will let it run until tomorrow if need be and then if it continues to run I will interrupt it.  I will let you know.  Once more thank you for your generous help!

Comment: No problem! Might be worth printing something out at each iteration of the loop so you can monitor progress. Also, I guess you want to save off the final dataframe? I would suggest the following amendments: Add `all_companies_df.to_csv(DATA_DIR + 'all_companies_data.csv')` to the very end of the file (non-indented). And add the line `print('Loading data from file: ', _company_fn)` indented in the for loop.

Comment: Thank you Seth.  I checked the files and I made some observations which I included in my post since there I have more space.  Perhaps you can help me once you read my comments.

Comment: Let's say your dictionary of dataframes is called `company_dfs_dict`. Would something like this work: `company_names, company_dfs = company_dfs_dict.keys(), company_dfs_dict.values()`. Then concatenate all `company_dfs` horizontally with `all_df = pd.concat(company_dfs_dict)` (which will match indices). Then, assuming all dfs have the same columns (in same order), set the multi-index cols as: `all_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([company_names, company_dfs[0].columns])`. After which you can do: `all_df.ffill()` to forward fill the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

csv_files = list(Path('path/to/csv/dir').glob('*.csv'))

dfs = []

for csv in csv_files:
    company_name = csv.stem.split('_')[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)\
           .assign(company = company_name)\
           .set_index('company', append=True)
    dfs.append(df)
```

The call the `read_csv` should parse the date as it reads the column in as an index.